# Gigabyte Z590 Aorus Ultra BIOS does not boot with 4 x 32 GB DDR4?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr, intel-core-i9

I got a new PC configuration as described below (in the screenshots) with 4 x 32GB sticks. The system works fine with following memory configurations:

**Configuration #1**

- A1 - 32GB
- A2 - NONE
- B1 - NONE
- B2 - NONE

**Configuration #2**

- A1 - NONE
- A2 - 32GB
- B1 - NONE
- B2 - NONE

**Configuration #3**

- A1 - 32GB
- A2 - 32GB
- B1 - NONE
- B2 - NONE

None of the other permutations work. The system doesn't even boots the bios logo with non-working configurations. Windows **does** detect 4 DIMM slots (see the screenshot below).

[image: Task Manager]

**Solutions already tried**,

- Updated to latest BIOS version
- Resetting CMOS
- Reinstalling the CPU & CPU fan
- Enabled X.M.P. profile
- Setting the DRAM frequency to 2933MHz, 2400MHz, and 3200MHz
- Changed the voltage to 1.35V

Before I start an RMA, I want to try some more solutions that can avoid the whole RMA process, because I don't want to be without a PC for a week.

[Full System Configuration](https://www.dropbox.com/s/74i1skq33bsuhu9/System%20Information%20-%202021-04-02.html?dl=0)

**System Configuration Summary**

[image: Processors]

[image: System]

[image: Memory]

Comment: Do your modules meet this specification: “Support for non-ECC Un-buffered DIMM 1Rx8/2Rx8/1Rx16 memory modules”?

Comment: Apologies for not knowing that but here's the link to my memory modules - https://www.dropbox.com/s/knfuse1u99v8mkn/2021-03-31%2016.19.15.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Are those modules on the QVL? 32 GB module support is pretty sparse so support is pretty specific.

Comment: Unfortunately its NOT on the QVL list; I should have checked this earlier. I used Newegg & their pre-configured are not reliable & return policy sucks. But still two sticks work, and single stick doesn't work in B1/B2 but works in A1/A2.

Comment: It not working in B1 and B2 is not actually that shocking.  Since that’s the second channel.  I assume A1 and B1 doesn’t work? That should be single channel mode, or would be typically single channel, and would be the only other configuration I expected to work if all 4 modules didn’t work.  I suspect the 128 GB has specific configuration limitations

Comment: Found the solution. The configuration was very frequency specific, I configured the frequency to 2933MHz & voilà it worked. All banks combined have now 128GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the DRAM frequency to exact 2933MHz as described in the motherboard/processor specification and all worked.

https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z590-AORUS-ULTRA-rev-10/sp#sp

> 10th Generation Intel® Core™ i9/i7 processors Support for DDR4 **2933**/2666/2400/2133 MHz memory modules

[image: Task Manager]